# The method obtain() is undefined for the type Message

Tags: java, android, methods, polling

I'm trying to implement the polling code I found on [this blogspot post](http://androidyou.blogspot.nl/2011/04/android-intentservice-how-to-write.html). In it there is the following line:

```
Message msg=Message.obtain();
```

I get an error saying that `The method obtain() is undefined for the type Message`. So I now wonder whether I am doing something wrong or whether this blogpost is simply wrong?

Below a little more code. Any tips would be very welcome!

```
@Override
public void run() {
    // just call the handler every 3 Seconds

    Message msg=Message.obtain();
    Bundle data=new Bundle();
    data.putString("k", "value" + System.currentTimeMillis() );
    msg.setData(data);
```

ps: I know that this is not the most optimal way of polling and that I should be using the AlarmManager. But seeing that it is just a prototype and we'll be using push messages lateron, I just wanted the most simple polling possibility out there..

Comment: Try to locate the import used for the object Message. It may be the wrong one

Comment: @azerto00 - Ahhh, I now see the problem. I have a class called Message in the package, which I guess it takes it from. I manually imported android.os.Message, and now it doesn't give the error anymore. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: It happens sometimes ... you're welcome